# Where LogonWorkstations not empty and where populated

Tags: powershell, active-directory

Either of these filters sets give me all or nothing to one Value.

```
    $combined = get-aduser -filter {name -like "blah*"} -properties LogonWorkstations
    $noWS = $combined | Where -filter {$_.LogonWorkstations -eq $null}
    $isWS = $combined | Where -filter {$_.LogonWorkstations -ne $null}
    $noWS.count
    $isws.count
    $noWS = $combined | Where -Filter {$_.LogonWorkstations -like ""}
    $isWS = $combined | Where -Filter {$_.LogonWorkstations -like "*"}
    $noWS.count
    $isws.count
```

Comment: Can you show us the actual output and what you expect it to be?

Comment: This is a query that will return over a 1000 results. About 1 out of 100 will have the LogonWorkstations attribute populated with possibly multiple computer names. Both need to be captured empty and populated.

Answer (score 1):

one possible problem with your code may be the comparison you are making. the `$Null` should always be on the *left* of a comparison so that both collections and type-coercion will work properly in a comparison. for the details on that, please do a search for ...

```
powershell null on the left
```

however, there is a somewhat simpler way to test for "nothing/something" in a `Where-Object` or `.Where()` call. just use `-not $_` or `$_`. here's an example that uses the local account cmdlets since i lack access to the AD cmdlets ...

```
'Total User Count    = {0}' -f $LocalUserList.Count
'Blank LastLogon     = {0}' -f $LocalUserList.Where({-not $_.LastLogon}).Count
'Non-Blank LastLogon = {0}' -f $LocalUserList.Where({$_.LastLogon}).Count
```

output ...

```
Total User Count    = 9
Blank LastLogon     = 6
Non-Blank LastLogon = 3
```

those numbers agree with what i see when i check manually. [*grin*]